# Issue with Closure Template (soy templates) rendering via Javascript & jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-closure-templates, soy-templates

I'm using javascript along with jQuery to render the [closure templates](https://github.com/google/closure-templates) (soy templates). I'm follwing its [hello world](https://github.com/google/closure-templates/blob/master/javascript/examples/simple-usage.html) example.
My jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3r9mo8v7/1/) .

As described in the [example](https://github.com/google/closure-templates/blob/master/javascript/examples/simple-usage.html), the following code works,

`document.write(soy.examples.simple.helloWorld());`

& provides

> Hello world!

But when used along with jQuery to dynamically insert the closure template's content, its always  returns empty, nothing gets appended.
`$('#withoutContent').append(soy.examples.simple.helloWorld());`

Ironically,on further looking, the following jQuery works correctly

`$('#withContent').append(soy.examples.simple.helloWorld().content);`

i'm facing this issue while upgrading from a very old version of closure templates. We have a lot of such templates, updating each one's usage in javascript to use `.content` is  cumbersome & errorprone. 
Why isn't jQuery able to properly get the contents of the template??

Answer (score 2):

> Why isn't jQuery able to properly get the contents of the template?

A call to `soy.examples.simple.helloWorld()` returns this object:

```
{
  constructor: function(){goog$soy$data$SanitizedContent.call(this)},
  content: "Hello world!",
  contentDir: null,
  contentKind: { ... },
  getContent: function(){return this.content},
  toString: function(){return this.content}
}
```

As you can see, it's not HTML, it has a couple of properties and methods - one of them is `toString()`, which returns the `.content`.

`document.write()` expects a string argument. If you pass something else (for example the object above) then it will call `.toString()` for you automatically. This is why

```
document.write(soy.examples.simple.helloWorld());
```

works.

jQuery's `$.append()` accepts all kinds of things - plain strings, single DOM nodes, DOM node lists, other jQuery objects, functions - and does the appropriate thing for each argument type. But in exchange for this flexibility it won't simply convert its argument to string. Some random object jQuery does not recognize will be discarded. This is why

```
$('#withoutContent').append(soy.examples.simple.helloWorld());
```

does not work.

> updating each one's usage in javascript to use .content is cumbersome & errorprone.

If you can type`$('...').append()` in all of those locations, then you can type `.content` in all of those locations.